# Postgresql-16 - SSPI configuration not working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-16

**Issue** - Failing to set up SSPI connection for Postgresql-16

**Config**

*pg_ident*
looks as follows

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
mapname username1@biz       username
mapname username2@biz       username
```

*pg_hba*
looks as follows

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only 
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
#== lines for specific users for SSPI (or anything else) BEFORE the catchall lines ==
# IPv4 local connections for SSPI: 
host    all             username1        127.0.0.1/32            sspi  map=mapname   
host    all             username2        127.0.0.1/32            sspi  map=mapname
# IPv6 local connections for SSPI: 
host    all             username1        ::1/128                 sspi  map=mapname   
host    all             username2           ::1/128                 sspi  map=mapname   
#===================================================================================
# IPv4 local connections: 
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections: 
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

After restart of the services I get the following error:

> connection failed: :1), port 54321 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

if I comment all the lines except the one with sspi config - I get the error -

> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption.

The users are set up in the DB and I can login to the db server using both accounts.
What am I missing?

Comment: Your sspi lines in the hba only match username1 and username2, but the error message says that you are not using either one of those, so it makes sense that no hba lines match.